# Vue stops tracking array changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

So i'm trying to change an array by removing items that I don't want to be displayed on the page at certain screen sizes. It works and my array is updated properly but after a while the DOM becomes out of sync with the array.

I'll try to explain...

My original array is in the data object so it's reactive, I then clone that array inside a method by doing: `const clonedArray = this.list.slice(0)`

I then change the data by doing: `const updateArray = clonedArray.splice(numberToSlice)`

I then push the updated array onto a new data object by doing: `this.newList = updateArray`

And the method is firing on page resize, and `numberToSlice` changes dependent on what browser size we're on.

I'm displaying my data on the page inside a V-FOR to display elements of the array.

When I resize the browser it works 3/4 times and then the items on the page disappear but if I look in Vue dev tools the array is still being updated but not displayed in the DOM or the page.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help, I tried to explain this as best as I could but if you need anything else let me know.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <isotope :list="list" id="root_isotope" class="card-layout" :options='option'>
        <div class="article-card" v-for="element in newList" :key="element.id">
          <article-card></article-card>
        </div>
      </isotope>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ArticleCard from '~components/article-card.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      ArticleCard
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    this.handleResize()
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize: function() {
      if (screen.width < 1020) {
        this.multipleOf = 2
      } else if (screen.width < 1440) {
        this.multipleOf = 3
      } else {
        this.multipleOf = 4
      }
      this.checkingArray()
    },
    checkingArray: function() {
      // checking if the data thats returned is a multiple of 2, 3 or 4
      if (this.list.length % this.multipleOf === 0) {
        // display all of the items
        // if not slice array so it's a multiple of 2, 3 or 4
      } else {
        let numberToSlice = Math.floor(this.list.length / this.multipleOf) * this.multipleOf
        let clonedArray = this.list.slice(0)

        let alteredArray = clonedArray.splice(numberToSlice)
        this.newList = alteredArray

        console.log(this.newList)
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      multipleOf: null,
      newList: [],
      list: [
        {
          name: 'Article 1',
          id: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'Article 2',
          id: 2
        },
        {
          name: 'Article 3',
          id: 3
        },
        {
          name: 'Article 4',
          id: 4
        },
        {
          name: 'Article 4',
          id: 5
        },
        {
          name: 'Article 4',
          id: 6
        },
        {
          name: 'Article 4',
          id: 7
        },

      ],
      selected: null,
      option: {
        masonry: {
          gutter: 40
        }
      }
    }
  },
</script>
```

Comment: pls, show the code of this page. Actions on arrays and v-for in html

Comment: Since no code is provided its difficult to know where the problem is....but can suggest you to check http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: @OlegShleif I've added the code in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this over the weekend, I was pushing the wrong "modified array" to the new list that I was looping over.

I didn't need to put my spliced array into another variable. So I removed `let altered array` (these should be consts I know) and then changed `this.newList = alteredArray` to `this.newList = clonedArray` ...not too sure why this was knocking the DOM out of sync?

But it's now fixed.